# MarkLogic Cluster - Add data in 1st host & update in 2nd host throws error

Tags: updates, marklogic, mlcp, data-ingestion

MarkLogic setup is as follows

- 3 hosts

Data confniguration
 - 1 master forest on each host
 - 1 replica for each host on different host

We have MarkLogic cluster (3 hosts) with failover) deployed on Azure VMs

We are using MarkLogic ContentPump (MLCP) to ingest data into MarkLogic

This is what we have implemented

- Installed Java on 1st host
- Copied MLCP tool
- Ingested data by providing 1st server as host parameter

Now we got batch of xmls to update back to MarkLogic

With failover implementation, due to some reason 1st host is not available, so when i tried to ingest data thru 2nd host, i started getting error that record was ingested in different host, so update can't happen from here.

So i would like to know the best practices to be followed for ingestion process

Comment: How many forests does you database have?  Are they distributed across the cluster?  Have you setup replicas for your database forests?  Have you setup replicas for your Security database forest/s?  You will need to provide some architecture details before your question can be answered.

Comment: Added info in original question, security forest failover setup is not configured yet

Comment: Hello Michael, i have added related info in question, can you please suggest on how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the system to reliably failover, you will also need to setup replicas for the Security, App Services & any other system database you may be using as part of your architecture.

The reason you are unable to connect to the other hosts is that the Security database is on host 1, so you are unable to authenticate.  Once that is configured for failover, you should no longer run into those issues.

The documentation covers that setup here:

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/config-both-failover#id_57935